# Is it possible to add a category to an Objective-C meta-class?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, metaclass, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

I would assume... NO. But wouldn't it be nice if instead of...

`NSStringFromClass(SomeClass)`

you could...

```
@interface      Class (ToString)
@property (readonly) NSString* stringValue;
@end
@implementation Class (ToString)
- (NSString*) stringValue { return NSStringFromClass(self); }
@end
```

and subsequently use...

```
SomeClass.stringValue
```

I'm sure there's a good reason the meta-heirarchy prevents this (although it seems like a half-truth when it's said that `Class`es (and `Protocols`, and `Methods`, etc) are-indeed "real" `Objects`)... when a lot of the "stuff" that makes a `NSObject` an `Object` can NOT be performed on a "metaclass".

Can anyone shed a light on this functional difference / offer an alternative (i.e.  `resolveClassMethod:` that might achieve similar result?

Comment: Protocols and methods are **not** objects.

Comment: Using the Protocol class is almost completely deprecated, @alexgray: http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/runtime/Protocol.h The entire header is wrapped in `#if __OBJC2__`

Answer (score 4):

Since an instance method of a metaclass is just a class method on the non-meta class, why not simply add a category on the original (non-meta) class?

```
@implementation NSObject (Name)

+ (NSString *)className
{
    return NSStringFromClass(self);
}

@end
```

Comment: duh, I forgot you CAN just treat them like `NSObject`s!